# Wordpress ACF field value passed to popup

Tags: wordpress, popup, advanced-custom-fields

In Wordpress, I'm trying to pass a youtube url created using ACF to a Popupmaker popup. I've tried this:

```
<?php if($video_file){ ?>
                        <a class="video_popup" href="?video_path=<?php echo $video_file ?>"> See Video</a>
```

and then this in the popup:

```
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="<?php echo $_GET["video_path"] ?>
```

Any ideas please...

Comment: Use console/debugg to show you what's in $video_file variable.
what is "?video_path" u mean $video_path ?

Comment: I see the $video_file value in the source but I'm not able to access it in the popup. I tried to pass it on the url .../?video_path=...and use $_GET but that didn't work.